# Cor de link declarado no string.xml (Versões abaixo do N)

Tags: android

Tenho o seguinte texto declarado no **string.xml**:

```
<string name="TITLE_EXAMPLE"><![CDATA[
    <p>Para entrar em contato com nossa Central:</p>
    <p><b>Brasil: Capitais</b></p>
    <p> <a href="tel:+5541123123123" style="color:#E29800"> 5541123123123</a> </p>
    ]]>
</string>
```

Como faço para aplicar uma determinada cor no **ahref** ?

Mesmo com **style** não está funcionando!

**[EDIT]**

Segundo a sugestão do [aldeir Psr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99718/valdeir-psr) :

```
TextView contact = findViewById(R.id.contact);

String html;
contact.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSIONS_CODE.N) {
        html = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.codeHtml), FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS);
    } else {
        html = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.codeHtml));
    }
    
    contact.setText(html);
```

Funciona apenas em versões do **N** para cima!

Gostaria de aplicar em todas as versões!

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar HTML em TextView ou similar, é necessário utilizar a classe [Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html), nativa do Android.

Essa classe tem um método chamado [fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) que serve justamente para essa função.

No caso de um TextView, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);

String html;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSIONS_CODE.N) {
    html = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.codeHtml), FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS);
} else {
    html = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.codeHtml));
}

textView.setText(html);
```

Comment: E para versões abaixo do **N**? pode ser feito tbm?

Comment: Pode sim. Basta utilizar `String html = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.codeHtml));`

Comment: não funcionou em abaixo do N

Comment: Verifica dessa forrma, com a tag font. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011685

Comment: Valdeir Psr, também não funcionou! Assim, percebi que ele usa o **colorAccent** pra esta cor, então criei um **Theme** com **<item name="colorAccent">@color/verde</item>** e apliquei ao **TextView**,  temporariamente me serve, mas vou pesquisar mais a respeito! Obrigado!